# Read graph from file and convert into array Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I need to read graph matrix from txt file. For example

```
4
0 1 1 0 
1 0 1 0 
1 1 0 1 
0 0 1 0
```

This is input file. First number is number of vertices. I tried something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file.getAbsolutePath());
int n = sc.nextInt();
int [][] graph = new int [n][n];
for (int x =0; x<n; x++)
    for (int y=0; y<n;y++)
        graph[x][y] = sc.nextInt();
```

But I'm getting `InputMismatchException`. I know what it means but I don't understand whats wrong. File contains `int` type characters and i'm using `nextInt()`; Any suggestions? Maybe easier way to convert matrix into array? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong constructor for `Scanner`. You are using this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String), which creates `Scanner` which has the string as the input stream.

Change constructor to `new Scanner(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()))`.

Comment: Now it says Unhandled exception java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: @Mak so you should handle the exception. Use a `try/catch` block, think what you want to do when the file is not there, and write that in the handler.